# SQLQuery works on SQLite browser but not Qt5.11.2

Tags: sql, sqlite, qt, qsqlquery

Following command works for the [sqlite browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/), not sure why it fail with Qt5.11.2

```
    using namespace edatabase;

    QSqlQuery query;
    QString const command("with ab as (select a.* from recorded_face_whitelist_log a union all select "
                          "b.* from recorded_face_log b)SELECT ID, FaceID, Image FROM "
                          "(SELECT ab.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FaceID ORDER BY DATE DESC, TIME DESC) "
                          "as seqnum FROM ab) ab WHERE seqnum = 1 ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC LIMIT 5");
    //query.prepare(command);
    query.exec(command);

    if(!query.lastError().isValid()){
        //do something
    }else{
        QLOG_DEBUG()<<__func__<<query.lastError()<<"\ncommand:"<<command;
    }
}
```

Error message:

QSqlError("1", "Unable to execute statement", "near "(": syntax error")

How could I solve this bug?Thanks

Edit : I copy the command print by the QLOG_DEBUG to the sqlite browser, it works. The command do not has any special characters, so I should not need any "\", weird.

Comment: Window functions were introduced in version 3.25.0 of SQLite. Check the version that you use.

Comment: @forpas Thanks, you are right.